# blocking select() from multiple sockets

Tags: c, unix, select, blocking

Unix/C question here.

I have multiple sockets that I am trying to poll for periodic data.  I don't want select to wait indefinitely so I have a timeout in place and I'm running in a loop.   I have found that once a socket is ready to read, **it is always ready to read**. As in, I cannot have select go to sleep when there is no data to be read from any of the sockets.

```
for (i = 0; i < n_connections; i++) {
  FD_SET( sockfd[i], &master );
  if (sockfd[i] > fdmax) 
    fdmax = sockfd[i];
  }

for(;;) {
  int nready = 0;
  timeout.tv_sec  = 1;
  timeout.tv_usec = 0;
  read_fds = master;
  if ( (nready = select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL)) == -1 ) {
    fprintf( stderr, "Select Error\n" );
    return FAILURE;
  }
  printf( "Number of ready descriptors: %d\n", nready );

  for (i = 0; i <= fdmax; i++) {
    if (FD_ISSET(i, &read_fds)) {
      if (( nbytes = recv(i, buf, sizeof(buf), 0)) <= 0 ) {
        if (nbytes == 0) {
          //connection closed
          printf("Socket %d hung up\n", i );
        }
        else {
          fprintf( stderr, "Recv Error %d\n", nbytes);
        }
      }
    else {
      printf( "Data Received on %d: %s\n", i, buf );
    }
  }
} // end file descriptor loop
```

It seems that after my first read, the 1 second timeout no longer applies and the socket is always "ready to read", even if there are 0 bytes available.  How can I get select to sleep until data comes in (for the one second, or by switching the final argument to NULL, indefinitely waiting for data to come in on the socket?)

Output:

```
Number of Ready Descriptors: 2
Data Received on 4: GreetingsChap
Data Received on 5: HiMatengsChap
Loop...
Number of Ready Descriptors: 2
Socket 4 hung up
Socket 5 hung up
Loop...
Number of Ready Descriptors: 2
Socket 4 hung up
Socket 5 hung up
Loop...
```

Thank you,

Note: Code updated for clarity
Updated based on @yvesBraumes suggestions - still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you calling `FD_SET()` before each `select()`? I notice you're simply assigning `read_fds` to `master`. `FD_COPY()` might be more appropriate.

Comment: What do you mean by "ready to read"? What is select() returning and what is read() returning in this case?

Comment: @chrisaycock, I am using FD_SET before.  I'm FD_SETing the master list of file descriptors, then assigning (which is what you see).  Posix allows for this and most examples I have found use it.

Comment: @Arc, select will always return the number of open sockets I have (in this case, it's 3).  Read will return the number of bytes sent from the server on the first pass, then 0 in subsequent loops

Comment: Sorry for my quick answer. I did not read the question well enough. I have a question: is your file descriptor a File? I found that on Linux, file descriptors in select() are always ready even though returning 0 in the next read() call.

Comment: @yvesBaumes, file descriptor is a TCP socket.

Comment: I don't see your code checking out the timeout value once select() returns. I think you must. Try with a NULL pointer instead of timeout=1sec .

Comment: @yvesBaumes, with timeout parameter set to NULL, select still does not block, instead following "nbytes == 0" path which prints "Socket x hung up"  First data packet from server is printed ("Data received path"), then non-blocking infinite loop.

Comment: Which platform are you using?

Comment: @yvesBraumes - 64 bit linux - RHEL 5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you detect that a connection is closed, remove the socket from the fd set, otherwise `select` is going to report them (`Socket 4 hung up`).. select is not edge triggered, if you don't handle the event, it's going to report it again.

Comment: I want the connection to remain open, and have select only report when there is unread data on the socket.  The data only appears periodically (once every few seconds), so I don't want a constant poll to waste CPU cycles.  Also, this needs to scale to many connections, so I can't do a thread-per-connection approach.  The "Socket Hung Up" isn't technically true in this case.  I want the descriptor to be "Not Ready" (and thus have select not return), until data is actually available on the open socket.

Comment: sorry I'm not sure what you want. the peer closed its write socket.. you've read all the data. so it's never going to send you more data. why do you keep the socket in the read set?

Comment: BTW if you really want to be able to scale, you're probably looking for epoll/kqueue

Comment: The server will be sending more data.  I want select to block until that data arrives on the socket.  recv() is returning 0 bytes available even though select() is saying the descriptor can be read.  The TCP connection will eventually get more data, I just want no processing to happen until that data appears.

Conversely, if I remove that descriptor from the fd_set, how will select work when the next batch of data appears?  I don't want to have to re-establish the TCP connection after every block of data.

Comment: if recv returns 0, it means that it won't send you any more data (please read the manual if you don't believe me). and select() will signal you that the socket is ready for read. which it really is (again, it's level triggered). handle it.

Comment: I figured out the issue.  Thank you for your help.  The server was closing the connection without my knowledge (even though the connection is supposed to be maintained)  I apologize for being hard headed about this.  Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, if recv returns 0 (and not -1, with errno=EWOULDBLOCK), the socket is closed. You should call `close()` on it as well, and take it out of the `select()` call. Otherwise it will remain in WAIT1 and release `select()` each time.

Answer (score 0):

You are using FD_ISSET incorrectly.  You need to be passing a socket ID to the "fd" parameter, not an index:

```
if (FD_ISSET(i, &read_fds))...
```

needs to be

```
if (FD_ISSET(sockfd[i], &read_fds))...
```

Likewise with `recv`.