# Binding/listening on multiple ports, is pthreads the correct way?

Tags: c, linux

I noticed that netcat doesn't let you listen on a port-range just individual ports. I wrote a basic netcat-like program in C with a client and a server functions. I am now investigating what the best way would be to listen on multiple ports.

I would aim for usage like: program localhost 200 300 ( where 200 is beginning and 300 is ending port).

Is pthreads the best way to do this? Bind/listen on each thread then when a connection is made join them back up?

```
 iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, bind_function, (void*) somename);
 pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
```

Threading is really new ground and I am not sure if there is a simpler way, or how you would use iret1 (the return value) further. Can anyone add to this?

Notes for Dolda2000:

A usage example on epoll I came across:

```
for (j = 1; j < argc; j++) {
        fd = open(argv[j], O_RDONLY);
        if (fd == -1)
            errExit("open");
        printf("Opened \"%s\" on fd %d\n", argv[j], fd);

        ev.events = EPOLLIN;            /* Only interested in input events */
        ev.data.fd = fd;
        if (epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd, &ev) == -1)
            errExit("epoll_ctl");
    }
```

My Binding code:

```
if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, server_len) < 0)
        error("ERROR");
        listen(sockfd,5);

newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &clilen);
```

Comment: If you just want to listen, see @Dolda2000's answer.  There are some things that would motivate threads over select, but just listening to ports isn't one of them.

Comment: IIRC each thread has an ~8mb overhead by default, forking is typically lighter for small programs (<8mb) but select/poll/epoll would be even lighter

Answer (score 2):

Surely, it would be easier and less resource-intensive to use `select`/`poll`/`epoll` instead?

I'm not sure exactly what you're having trouble with, so here's some example code using `poll`:

```
int listentoall(int firstport, int lastport)
{
    int i, nsk;
    int nfd = lastport - firstport + 1;
    struct pollfd fds[nfd];
    struct sockaddr_in name;

    memset(&name, 0, sizeof(name));
    name.sin_family = AF_INET;
    for(i = 0; i < nfd; i++) {
        fds[i].fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        name.sin_port = htons(firstport + i);
        bind(fds[i].fd, (struct sockaddr *)&name, sizeof(name));
        listen(fds[i].fd, 5);
        fds[i].events = POLLIN;
    }

    while(1) {
        poll(fds, nfd, -1);
        for(i = 0; i < nfd; i++) {
            if(fds[i].revents & POLLIN) {
                nsk = accept(fds[i].fd, NULL, NULL);
                for(i = 0; i <nfd; i++)
                    close(fds[i].fd);
                return(nsk);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I just wrote this code right now without compiling it, so there may well be typos and whatnot, and it obviously does no error checking, but perhaps it's enough to explain the general structure?

Comment: Im sorry, how would you iterate through the port bindings in the range and register them for epoll? Also am I right in thinking that select isn't sufficient for the full port range 1- 65k? Once a connection is received on any of the ports I want them all to unblind and stop listening apart from the one that is connected

Comment: What is it that you're wondering about iterating all the sockets? Is it the API you don't understand, or something else? You would be right in thinking that `select` doesn't go that far, however; but both `poll` and `epoll` would work.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I updated my post with the example api usage and below it how I am binding/listening/accepting for one port. What I mean by iteration is that I could do a for loop to bind/listen the port range, but then I am unsure about the interaction of the epoll with the accept().

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to do it is with select or poll, or epoll on linux. Here are a couple of good threads discussing:

[blocking select() from multiple sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574031/blocking-select-from-multiple-sockets)

[selecting among multiple sockets that are ready to be read from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097745/selecting-among-multiple-sockets-that-are-ready-to-be-read-from)